# xmobar - dynnetwork not picking up usb0

Tags: networking, usb, xmobar

I have xmobar running in xmonad displaying network traffic summary via the dynnetwork monitor.  It works fine with eth0 and wlan0, as wired and wireless network are identified on this machine, but the usb0 interface is not picked up when in use.  bmon sees and reports traffic on usb0.  Is there some way to have dynnetwork pick up usb0 traffic when it is in use or is it just not designed to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the author for identifying the problem.  The usb0 interface was being raised after xmobar was run and the Net plugin only identifies active interfaces at initial runtime.  By raising the usb0 interface before xmobar (or restarting xmabar after the interface is raised) it will be detected and reported normally.  Hopefully a fix on the way.